# Axios get and display output in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to output the data from axios get method but at the moment {event.title} is not giving any text eventhough the console.log shows that I recieved the data from the database. I am new to react native and have done plenty of reasearch but I can't seem to fix this problem.
Any comment and idea would be very much appreciated!

```
 const Events = () => {
    
    const[event, getEvents] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllEvents();
   }, []);
state = {
        result: []
    }

      const getAllEvents = () => {
          axios
          .get(url)
          .then((response) => {
              const result = response.data;
              getEvents({result});
            
              console.log('Data has been recieved!');
              console.log(result);

          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log('Error retrieving data!');
              
          })
      }

      
if(getEvents.length > 0) {
    return(

        <View>
        
            <ScrollView>
        
            <Text style = {styles.bigtext}>Eventet</Text>

            <View nativeID = "allRows" style = {{flexDirection: "column",justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}> 
       
                <View nativeID = "row" style = {{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center", margin: 1}}> 
                
                    <View style = {styles.event}> 
                   
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { showModal(); }}> 
                    <Image style = {{borderTopLeftRadius:10, borderTopRightRadius:10, height: 159, width: 159}}  source={require('../../assets/45.png')}  />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                       {  result.map( event =>   <Text onPress={() => { showModal(); }} style = {styles.eventTitle}>{event.title}</Text>)}
                        
                    
                    </View>

                </View>

            </View>
            
            </ScrollView>
              
        </View>
    
   );  
    }
    else {
        return(
            <View>
            <Text>No events!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: You set a state named "event" but then you try to map through "result". Should you not try to map through "event"?

Comment: You initially declare event to be a string, so you need to fix that by doing "const [event, getEvents] = useState([]);". If it still doesn't work, then you need to double-check that event is actually an array. Otherwise .map will not work.

Comment: It seems to be okay. I mean, I don't know what "result" in the backend code you showed me contains. That is the part that needs to be an array. If response.data (on the frontend) contains anything else than an array, then you can't iterate through it using .map.

Comment: If it contains key-value pairs, then it's an object, not an array. An array looks like this: ["a", "b", "c"]. An object looks like this: {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}.

Comment: Could you perhaps show me what your console.log(result) shows?

Comment: Are you still doing "getEvents({result});" or have you fixed it to be "getEvents(result);" like my answer below suggests? (my answer also changed the variable name, but that can be ignored for now)

Comment: I wonder if you would [consider undeleting this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577602/node-js-program-exhibits-image-upload-error). I don't mind that my suggestions in comments were deleted, but it looks like you deleted a good answer as well. We try to discourage question deletion where an answer has been posted, since it may help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

When you do "const result = response.data;" you are declaring a local variable which can not be reached outside of the ".then" function. But even if you declared it at a wider scope, it would still be set to null on the next render. You need to use useState (and use it correctly).

```
const Events = () => {
    const[results, setResults] = useState([]);

    const getAllEvents = () => {
      axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
          setResults(response.data ?? []);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log('Error retrieving data!');
      })
    }
```

And then

```
{results.map(event => <Text onPress={() => {showModal();}} style = {styles.eventTitle}>{event.title}</Text>)}
```

I am assuming here that the content of response.data is an array. If it isn't, you will not be able to use .map

Comment: If you'd like, sure. "results" or "event", or whatever you want to call it, is defined within .map and can only be used within .map, so what you should call it depends on what you want it to be called.

Comment: Could you try logging the value of event (the variable I renamed to results) outside of the getAllEvents function?

Comment: By the way, "if(getEvents.length > 0)" won't work. It should be "if(event.length > 0)".

Comment: Oh, right. It should be "if(event.data.length > 0)" (and preferably also a null check to avoid errors). My bad.

Comment: event starts out as an empty object right? If so, then you have to first do a null check, then do the rest, e.g. "if(!!event && !!event.data && event.data.length > 0)". It might perhaps be simpler to put the whole thing in a try-catch, idk.

Comment: But honestly, you've got a lot more than one issue in your code. I don't think I can (or have the time to) help you much more than this.