# Node.js program exhibits image upload error

Tags: node.js, postman, image-upload

I made this post request that saves a title, description, solution and a photo in the database. Everything is required except for the photo. I am trying to make the image upload work but I am unable to put the path of the photo in postman because if I do something like `C:\Users\me\Desktop` it will cause an error. Is there a problem with the code or is there any other way I can fix this?

```
router.post('/problem', catchAsync (async (req, res) => {

const { title, description, solution, photo } = req.body;
let uploadPath;

// // 1) Check if title, description and solution exist
if (!title || !description || !solution) {
  
  res.json({
      status: "FAILED",
      message: "Please provide a title, description and solution!"
  })
  console.log("Success!");
  
}

photo = req.files.photo;
uploadPath = __dirname + '/uploads' + photo.name;

sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.send('File uploaded to ' + uploadPath);
});
    
//Save it in the database     
const newProblem = new Problem({
    title,
    description,
    solution,
    photo
});
console.log(newProblem);

newProblem.save().then(result => {

    res.json({
        status: "SUCCESS",
        message: "Success",
        data: result
        })

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({
        status: "FAILED",
        message: "Error",
        data: result,
    })

})
```

The error I get is this:

> Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: If the `catch()` block is triggered, what do you get in `err`?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Node, but I wonder if `sampleFile.mv` is async, and thus needs to be awaited?

Comment: Does it give any indication which part of your code is attempting to send a header? It is certainly true that one cannot set headers if headers have already been sent - maybe content is being sent, which would have forced headers to be sent?

Comment: I don't see it. In Postman I am sending the data as a raw file in the form of { "title": "blla blla blla", ... }, and the image as Body -> form-data -> KEY (File). When I click send it says that there is no text

Comment: I would expect `res.json()` to send `Content-Type: application/json` - would you have started sending a response body before that?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Ah, in the `if (!title || !description || !solution) {` should you return JSON and then exit? It looks like the program keeps on going even in this error condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238153/discussion-between-loki-and-halfer).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what point you were trying to make therefore I am not sure what I have to look into. Maybe it would help to tell me whether my server code is wrong and what I should do to fix it because I have been trying for quite some time and can't come up with something that works.

Comment: Can you look into the two other items I have mentioned? (1) `mv()` may be async, (2) error clause perhaps should exit in error condition. If you can respond on those two points, in detail, that might help readers assist further.

Comment: I assume the catch at the end is triggering because `Problem.save()` throws an exception, so I wonder if readers might need to understand what a Problem is. Think about how readers can replicate what you are seeing. I am not too familiar with Node, but I wonder if there is a Node playground that you can use to show the problem, like JS Fiddle.

Comment: I am a very beginner in nodejs so I hope you understand that it is quite hard to articulate every single thing, that's why I was looking for help. Since I don't know what is wrong with the code on my own, I am not expected to give immediate answers to questions. If I knew the solution I wouldn't be asking so maybe it is more helpful to not put any further pressure. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sure, I understand that - but if three suggestions are made by readers, there is an expectation that question authors look (and hopefully respond to) those three things.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is stemming from this part of the code

```
    sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.send('File uploaded to ' + uploadPath);
});
```

if the file upload is successful you send a response to the client, however the function still has more operations following it in which you attempt to send more responses to the client.  If the following code is required on a successful upload, you should not send a response right away, instead use a boolean flag and check this once everything else is complete, only then should you send the response to the client.

Comment: Also you mark the route as async, but you never use await anywhere, which makes the async moot.